# App links intent filters in assetlinks.json not working on Android

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, applinks

My app defines the intent filters to handle URL's from my site defined by

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
  <data android:host="www.host.com" android:scheme="http"/>
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
  <data android:host="www.host.com" android:scheme="https"/>
</intent-filter>
```

The app correctly detects URL's of the correct host but queries the user whether to open them in the app or browser. I tried using the App links verification as specified here: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html

As seen in my server logs, when installing the app, the device queries /well-known/assetlinks.json and it responds with a 200 status. Testing the digital assets file using the

`https://digitalassetlinks.googleapis.com/v1/statements:list?source.web.site=https://<domain1>:<port>&relation=delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls`

API and it found no errors.

The SHA256 in the assetlinks.json file was obtained using

```
keytool -list -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore
```

the same .keystore of which the app was signed.

Running `adb shell dumpsys package d` returns that the link verification status is "ask" meaning that verification failed. Why might verification be failing?

Comment: Hi @mohamed.ahmed were you able to solve this? I am having kind of similar issue. My android app link works for signed apk before uploading to the play store. stops working after taking it to live in the play store. refer the link for more info  
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57959217/android-app-link-not-working-after-the-application-is-made-live-in-play-store

Comment: Maybe you are put in your assets file (in server) the SHA256 from you local certificate. You need put the SHA256 from playGoogle. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61204765/496637

Answer (score 19):

For us it was Windows line endings!

Testing with "https://digitalassetlinks.googleapis.com/v1/statements:list?source.web.site=https://domain1:port&relation=delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls" proved invaluable as it gave us an "Could not parse statement list (not valid JSON)" error which led us to the problem.

TIP: It was good to use the 'Save File' button in the Android Studio App Links Assistant instead of copying and pasting as we did - that way it generates the file itself and is guaranteed not to have this issue.

Comment: This answer got me headed down the right path, but for me, it was actually the byte-order mark (BOM), not the line endings. I removed the BOM and the file worked just fine with Windows line endings. Please see my answer for details on how to remove the BOM.

Comment: I cut and pasted it into notepad first and it fixed the issue for me.  Could not find a Save File button.

Answer (score 18):

There are some common pitfalls which you should check twice (I don't say that you did it wrong. It is just a check list):

1. Verify that the `assetlinks.json` is valid and stored accessible from `https://example.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json` to do that you need to visit `https://digitalassetlinks.googleapis.com/v1/statements:list?source.web.site= https://example.com&relation=delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls`, there must be no errors.
2. If you link multiple domains at once, check that all domains are setup correctly as in step 1.
3. Make sure that those `<intent-filters>` which contain your `<data>` tags have the attribute `android:autoVerify="true"`.
4. Verify that you have the required `<meta-data>` tag in your `<application>` tag:

   ```
   <meta-data
       android:name="asset_statements"
       android:resource="@string/asset_statements"/>
   ```

   The content of the `asset_statements` string must be:

   ```
   <string name="asset_statements" translatable="false">[{\"include\": \"https://example.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json\"}]
   ```
5. Use for debug also the release signing certificate (don't be scared you cannot upload it accidentally) use this in your `build.gradle`:

   ```
   buildTypes {
       release {
           minifyEnabled true
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
       debug {
           debuggable true
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Also, I would add that the app links won't work if you have the same root host with different path values pointing to the same activity (if you implement it with .well-known process). I needed this to test my feature on my test servers and on production at the same time.

Comment: How will `@string/asset_statements` help? Especially if it has only one URL, while in `AndroidManifest` we have several.

Comment: Strange, but it helped when I added both domains (from `AndroidManifest`) to `asset_statements`. But later again didn't work, so I removed `<meta-data>`.

Answer (score 15):

Looking at [j__m](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38048936/android-intent-filter-verification-failure/43184948) comment, I found this.

1. In `AndroidManifest` write so:

   ```
    <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <!-- Write <data> tags with one attribute, if you use several domains. -->
        <data android:scheme="https" />
        <data android:host="example.com" />
    </intent-filter>
    <!-- Other domains-->
    <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data android:scheme="https" />
        <data android:host="server.com" />
    </intent-filter>
   ```

`android:autoVerify="true"` is needed for App Linking.

2. Create `assetlinks.json` using `Tools > App Links Assistant`. Then press `Open Digital Asset Links File Generator`, enter domain, application id, select `release` signing config and press `Generate Digital Asset Links File`. Then you can save file or copy to clipboard.
3. You can create several `assetlinks.json` files (for several applications) and join them into one JSON. To my mind it doesn't depend on Windows line endings (I used Notepad to concatenate JSONs). First time I auto-formatted it with Ctrl + Alt + L, and after uploading to domains App Link didn't work (probably because of later errors in `AndroidManifest`), so on the 2nd try I didn't format JSON. I created `assetlinks.json` for `release` and `debug` builds of the application.
4. Upload `assetlinks.json` to `https://example.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json` (in this answer I write: `example.com` and mean your domain like `company.name`). Check it with `https://digitalassetlinks.googleapis.com/v1/statements:list?source.web.site=https://example.com&relation=delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls`. The file and the domain have some [restrictions](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/heuristic-outcomes-by-ade-oshineye-6a360cc923ad). In my case everything was simple, we didn't change settings.
5. In your `DeepLinkActivity` you can parse URLs with regular expressions. Use `JUnit` to create tests. Call this method from `onCreate()`:

   ```
    private fun processDeepLink() {
        if (intent?.data?.isHierarchical == true) {
            val data = intent?.dataString
            if (intent?.action == Intent.ACTION_VIEW && data != null) {
                when {
                    REGEX.matches(data) -> // Get id and open some screen.
                    else -> // Either open MainActivity or skip this URL (open web browser instead).
                }
                finish()
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        val REGEX = "^https://example.com/some_request/(\\d+).*".toRegex()
    }
   ```

**Warning!** If you open a web browser from the application, you will fall into a loop. When clicking a link to your domain in the application, a browser won't appear, but your application will be opened automatically! What a surprise! So, in `processDeepLink` you should check the URL and open `MainActivity` when URL matches one of your masks. Skip others. Now a user will see a dialog with a list of browsers and your application (like in Deep Link). This happens because your application also handles links to your domains, like a browser.

You can also use `WebView` instead of a browser (not a good solution), open `Chrome Custom Tabs` or [`Chrome`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013416/is-there-any-way-in-android-to-force-open-a-link-to-open-in-chrome).

6. Use device with Android 6 or later.
7. If `https://digitalassetlinks.googleapis.com/v1/statements:list?source.web.site=https://example.com&relation=delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls` returned no errors, build the application. Create an Email message, SMS, QR-code or another application with a link to your domain. Click it, and App Link will open your application or Deep Link will show a dialog to choose an application.
   If App Link didn't work, read later.
8. In `LogCat` select `No Filters` and type `IntentFilter` into search box. There should be:

   ```
    I/IntentFilterIntentOp: Verifying IntentFilter. verificationId:2 scheme:"https" hosts:"example.com" package:"com.my_package".
    I/IntentFilterIntentOp: Verification 0 complete. Success:true. Failed hosts:.
   ```

Probably you will get:

```
I/IntentFilterIntentOp: Verifying IntentFilter. verificationId:0 scheme:"https" hosts:"example.com server.com" package:"com.my_package".
I/IntentFilterIntentOp: Verification 0 complete. Success:false. Failed hosts:server.com.
```

9. Later you will try to fix domains in the application, so sometimes you can launch for clean install:

   ```
    adb shell pm clear com.android.statementservice
   ```
10. Start `adb shell dumpsys package d` and find your domains. There should be:

    ```
    Package Name: com.my_package
    Domains: example.com server.com
    Status:  always : 200000000
    ```

But probably it will be:

```
Package Name: com.my_package
Domains: example.com server.com
Status: ask
```

See also https://chris.orr.me.uk/android-app-linking-how-it-works/. Strange, but in an emulator it wrote: `always`, while App Link didn't work.

I also tried `adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE -d "https://example.com"` to test App Link without a browser, but later it didn't work.

11. If you have several domains, comment (or remove) other domains in `AndroidManifest` (retain only one domain, for example, "example.com"). Then click a URL https://example.com/something and check it uses App Link.
    In my case I checked `release` and `debug` builds of the application. While the `debug` build worked with App Link, `release` didn't (and sometimes vise versa). I used the solution of [rekire](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48416681/2914140):

    ```
    <meta-data
        android:name="asset_statements"
        android:resource="@string/asset_statements"/>
    ```

and it helped for 2 domains, but later stopped, so I removed it. In the end I wrote in `AndroidManifest` `<data>` tags with one attribute as [j__m](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38048936/android-intent-filter-verification-failure/43184948) said.

Even if only one domain was failing, App Link was not working for other domains either. You can check domains one by one retaining only one domain each time in `AndroidManifest`.

See also http://androidideas.com/handling-app-links-in-android/, https://willowtreeapps.com/ideas/a-better-user-experience-for-deep-linking-on-android, https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations,

Answer (score 11):

For me, it came down to checking all the basics:

1. Verify my assetLinks file is good with this tool: (replace domain1:port with your domain)
   https://digitalassetlinks.googleapis.com/v1/statements:list?source.web.site=https://domain1:port&relation=delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls
2. Always test with a signed APK
3. Make sure the test device is running Android 6.0 or later (this is the one that bit me because I forgot it - on older versions of android, you always get the user prompt)

Answer (score 6):

For me, it was the fact that my `assetlinks.json` file was UTF-8 and contained a **byte-order mark** (BOM), which is a three-byte magic number at the head of the file that signals the encoding to a consuming program. The BOM is optional, and apparently the Google / Android tools do not like to see it. When it was present, Google's digital asset links verifier (URL below) gave me a "malformed JSON" error.

If you're using Visual Studio, here's how to determine if you have the BOM in your file, and remove it if necessary:

1. Right-click your assetlinks.json file.
2. Choose "Open With..." from the context menu.
3. Choose "Binary Editor" in the "Open With" dialog.
4. Examine the file bytes. If the file starts with `EF BB BF`, that's the problem.
5. Delete those characters (you can do this via either column) and save the file.
6. Re-upload the file and test it using the Google tools (URLs below) and it should work properly for you.

Here's the URL you can use to check your file (replace example.com with your actual URL):

https://digitalassetlinks.googleapis.com/v1/statements:list?source.web.site=https://example.com&relation=delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls

Answer (score 6):

### Update

So I resolved my issue. Not sure which one did it (might have been a combination), but this is what I did:

- Uninstalled "Google Play Services for Instant Apps": I had previously tinkered around with Instant Apps, so I thought maybe some old configurations might be sticking around like the debug package name, however this is unlikely.
- Stopped using proxies: Proxies are helpful for debugging network calls, but HTTP/2 might not be fully supported on the tools I'm using.
- Delete intent filter for legacy subdomains: **This is the big one**. One of my subdomains has been deprecated and is no longer available. In the AndroidManifest, if you have multiple hostnames declared for an activity that contains *at least one* autoVerify intent filter, each host is checked for the Digital Asset Link JSON file. *If autoVerify fails **for even one** of the hosts, then none of the hosts are auto verified.*

### Original

When I first faced this issue, it was because my network was blocking calls to Google's servers for verifying the app links.

As OP and other answers have touched on, in general the API call to endpoint:

> digitalassetlinks.googleapis.com

must be successful to bypass the chooser dialog. 
This is the web call the Android system makes, to verify the Digital Asset Link JSON file, and seems to be made upon app install/update. A helpful place to look is the Logcat, searching for items with the text "I/SingleHostAsyncVerifier:". If you see "--> true" at the end of the log, your app

Lately though, these calls have been failing for me due to what appears to be some bug which may have been introduced recently. The device is receiving this response from the API call above:

> Error: unavailable: Wrong content type in HTTP response headers while fetching statements from {host}/.well-known/assetlinks.json (which is equivalent to '{host}/.well-known/assetlinks.json'): expected 'Content-Type: application/json' but found text/html [11] while fetching Web statements from {host}./.well-known/assetlinks.json

It's been awhile since I last looked at these requests, so I don't remember what they looked like before. But it seems possible that there may have been some recent update involving App Links or the Android networking framework, where they switched over to protocol buffers for this feature (and forgot to support it in another one).

Another indication that things may have changed, is that the request path today appears different from the ones mentioned in the previous answers:

> https://digitalassetlinks.googleapis.com/google.digitalassetlinks.v1.AssetLinks/Check

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure this doesn't answer the original question, as I think it pre-dates Android App Bundles, but the thing that was ultimately causing a failure for me was that I'd enabled Google Play Console re-signing of the app (required for AABs) and therefore the SHA-256 fingerprint I was getting from `keytool` did not match the digital signature of the downloaded app.

Updating my `assetlinks.json` with the fingerprints from the console solved it.

Answer (score 1):

In our case we had 2 intent filters with applinks in our manifest: one with `autoVerify="true"` and one without.

So the verifier tried to verify domains for the 2nd intent filter and failed, and treated all our applinks as "not verified". You can find more details in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36229090/android-tries-to-verify-host-despite-androidautoverify-false).

You have to make sure every applink can be verified (which means adding `assetlinks.json` for every domain to be verified).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, `adb shell dumpsys package d` revealed that the `packageName` was incorrectly configured in `assetlinks.json`. I had used the `package` attribute value of my `manifest` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml`, but I should have used the `android.defaultConfig.packageId` value in my `build.gradle` file.

Answer (score 0):

System app selection window in two cases

1) User makes changes to settings related opening links by going to settings > apps > gear icon > opening links > select an app > open supported links > choose prompt every time.

2)Default app is not set by user and auto verify is not enabled in one of the app links supported app

I think in your case auto verify is enabled, so please check user settings.

Answer (score 0):

For me, don't change anything of `assetlinks.json` including trimming **blanks** and **line-breaks**.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the other answers here, I was able to find my issue. In spite of doing everything right. This was my problem.

- If your project is huge, chances are you have multiple android module dependencies. Check the merged manifest to find all the activities with intent filter(with autoverify = true).

How this can go wrong is simple. If a project has multiple autoverify urls, then the OS tries to verify it all. Even if one fails then the OS fails the verification of every URL.

Open the manifest file in your main app module, then choose the Merged Manifest option from the bottom tab. Now check the Manifest sources(list) on the right and manually look up manifest files of every library project.

In my case, a third-party library's auto verify flag was enabled. My two-day search comes to an end. Good luck to you.