# Your site 'www.xxxxx.com' has not been linked through the Digital Assets Link protocol to your app

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I have try many times for upload an instant app, but always get this error at google play console.

> Your site 'www.builtbee.com' has not been linked through the Digital Assets Link protocol to your app. Please link your site through the Digital Assets Link protocol to your app.

Here is my manifest....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data
        android:name="asset_statements"
        android:resource="@string/asset_statements" />

    <activity
        android:name=".Home"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        <meta-data
            android:name="default-url"
            android:value="https://www.builtbee.com" />

        <intent-filter
            android:autoVerify="true"
            android:order="1">

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
            <data android:host="www.builtbee.com" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/instantApp" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

and i have pass the digital asset link with my release keystore file.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvcTR.png

Am I miss something?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Digital Asset Link verified by Android Studio, but not pass in Google Play Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46037099/digital-asset-link-verified-by-android-studio-but-not-pass-in-google-play-conso)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I manage to solved it myself. This problem happen because i generate the *assetlinks.json* with my upload key, which is wrong. So i just edit the json file with my release key and put at .well-known folder then the problem solved.

Comment: you can accept my answer if it really helps. Thank you.

Comment: Other posters have also run into your issue @ https://stackoverflow.com/a/46138747/6668797 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/45884163/6668797

Answer (score 2):

Try to follow the steps provided in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/app-link-indexing.html#associatesite) and also see the discussion in the [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44497929/digital-assets-link-link-to-my-website).

> To add intent filters and URL handling, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Select **Tools > App Links Assistant**.
> 2. Click **Open URL Mapping Editor** and then click Add [image] at the bottom of the **URL Mapping** list to
>    add a new URL mapping.
> 3. Add details for the new URL mapping: [image]
>    **Figure 1**. Add basic details about your site's link structure to map URLs to activities in your app.
> 4. The App Links Assistant adds intent filters based on your URL mapping to the `AndroidManifest.xml` file, and highlights it in the **Preview** field. If you'd like to make any changes, click Open AndroidManifest.xml to edit the intent filter. (Learn more about intent filters in Android.)
> 5. To verify your URL mapping works properly, enter a URL in the Check URL Mapping field and click Check Mapping. If it's working correctly, the success message shows that the URL you entered maps to the activity you selected.

You can visit this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/getting-started/structure.html#basic-app) if you needed a reference about the structure of an instant app project in android.

Another thing, double check if `https://www.mywebsitename.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json` can be accessed from external network. To do this, switch to a public wifi and verify if the json file can load properly.

Refer to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44723755/instant-app-digital-asset-links-protocol) for further details

> Please check if your website asset link file is not behind some form
> of authentication, internal IP, or blocked by firewall. Play Store
> Developer Console can not access the digital asset link file if it is
> not publicly accessible.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If your app is enrolled into Google Play Signing, APKs should be signed with upload key, while assetlink.json should have release key fingerprint.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Kaze, I was having the same issue and finally figured out it was because you need to put in the digital asset link file, the app release key and not the upload key you pull from the google play console.

Comment: as answer follows other, you may leave the comment there. rather than making it new answer

Comment: My apologies, I don't think I had enough reputation points at the time to comment.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figure out the exact problem. It is the issue with SHA256. I provide SHA256 of my release key. However i need to provide the SHA provided by play console. Go appsigning section and copy SHA256 of your aap and replace it with your release SHA256 in assetlinks.json.