# Digital Asset Link verified by Android Studio, but not pass in Google Play Console

Tags: android, android-studio, deep-linking, android-instant-apps, android-studio-3.0

I try to publish my Android instant app to Google Play;
I link the app, which is named `helloinstantapp.instantapp.examples.chrisyttang.org` to the domain `https://csytang.github.io`. 
It has been verified by Android Studio[image] as you can see in the following image;

However, when I try to publish my app into Google Play with Google Play Console, I get the error that "the site `csytang.github.io` has not been linked through the DAL protocol to your app." Why this happen?

[image]

Comment: I’ve never encountered your issue, but you can try https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator for the same verification result. Though, try again with the built-in assistant. If it still stalls, you might have to insert the files into your project manually - let me know.

Comment: BTW, the package_name in your assetlinks.json should be just the application ID: helloinstantapp.instantapp.examples.chrisyttang.org

Comment: Now it works but still show not connect in google play

Comment: I revise the problem, @TWL thanks.

Comment: @csytang Did you by any chance enable [Google Play App Signing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423)? If yes, then you need to use the fingerprint provided by the Play Console, instead of the fingerprint used by Android Studio to sign the APK with (upload key). To do this, modify your `assetlinks.json` with the release key specified in the `Play Console > Release management > App signing`.

Comment: cool @Idolon it fixes my problems. Many thanks

Comment: thanks please see the acceptance

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Did you by any chance enable [Google Play App Signing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423)? If yes, then you need to use the fingerprint provided by the Play Console, instead of the fingerprint used by Android Studio to sign the APK with (upload key).
To do this, modify your `assetlinks.json` with the release key specified in the `Play Console > Release management > App signing`.

Comment: this fixes the bug

Comment: Release management > App signing 
showing - App signing certificate  & Upload certificate.

which fingerprint we have to use from this?

Comment: @Neal which one did you use ?

Comment: @AndreiBogdan I use App signing certificate and it works

Comment: I have upadated assetlinks.json with app signing key. But still getting same error like below:


'Your site 'b2c.utimf.com' has not been linked through the Digital Assets Link protocol to your app. Please link your site through the Digital Assets Link protocol to your app.'

Comment: I wish I could upvote this 10 times, thanks so much for this answer