# I tried to upload my instant app apks to Play store, it gives the following error

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I upload my instant app apks to Play store, it gives the following error :

> Your website `www.tomtop.com` has not yet been linked to your app through a digital asset link agreement. Please link your website to your app via digital asset link agreement.

I ran the [digital asset links generator](https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator), it returns successful for associating with my app and web site. Why do I get this error?

[image: Asset links check]

This is my AndroidManifest:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>

<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data
         android:scheme="https"
         android:host="www.tomtop.com"
         android:pathPrefix="/instant" />
</intent-filter>

<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data
        android:scheme="http"
        android:host="www.tomtop.com"
        android:pathPrefix="/instant" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: I posted my  instant app on Google Play Tip: Your website "www.tomtop.com" has not yet been linked to your app through a digital asset link agreement. Please link your website to your app via digital asset link agreement. But I click Associate Webside in Link Studio Link and verify is OK and test by https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator is ok too.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44497929/digital-assets-link-link-to-my-website

Comment: Base off of what you've provided, I don't see any cause for that error. I'd recommend filing your issue with Google so you can securely provide them with your IA for them to examine: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=316045&template=1018787

Comment: Have you checked if you are using the correct key (Google Play App-signing)? see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46037099/digital-asset-link-verified-by-android-studio-but-not-pass-in-google-play-conso/

Comment: As you said, my key is wrong, and now that I've solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Can you check **[Manage your app signing keys](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423)**, you need to use the fingerprint provided by the [Play Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/),instead of the fingerprint used by Android Studio to sign the APK with (upload key).

Step 1: Create an upload key

Step 2: Prepare your release

```
 1. Go to your Play Console.    
 2. Select an app. 
 3. On the left menu, select Release management  >  App releases. 
 4. Next to "Google Play App Signing," select Accept.
```

Step 3: Upload your signed app

Step 4: Register your app signing key with API providers

**Reference:-** [Enroll for app signing in the Google Play Console & secure your app using Google’s robust security infrastructure](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/09/enroll-for-app-signing-in-google-play.html)

[YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=2&v=PuaYhnGmeEk)