# Instant App Error: Your site 'website.com' has not been linked through the Digital Assets Link protocol to your app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-instant-apps

> **Error Message:** Your site 'website.com' has not been linked through the Digital Assets Link protocol to your app. Please link your site through the Digital Assets Link protocol to your app.

Hi

Dealing with this issues since past week. Did a lot of google and engaged play store support team also without any resolution. Therefore, posting it here hoping somebody would have already faced this issue too.

For instant app upload to play store I have already uploaded the assets json file to the specified path and I am able to get that file via simple GET request. So, there is no access control required over the asset json file.

In android studio also digital asset linking results in success as shown below:

[image]

But whenever I try to publish it to playstore it always gets stuck at below:

[image]

Any help would be highly appriciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you don't use App Signing and are sure you have the correct keys, thenfile your issue to Google @ https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=316045&template=1018787 They can take a look at it if you provide your app's package name.

Answer (score 2):

ok I figure out the exact problem. It is the issue with SHA256. I provide SHA256 of my release key. However i need to provide the SHA provided by play console. Go appsigning section and copy SHA256 of your aap and replace it with your release SHA256.

Answer (score 1):

You may refer with this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45893236/your-site-www-xxxxx-com-has-not-been-linked-through-the-digital-assets-link-pr?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) which encounters the same issue. Try to follow the steps provided in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/app-link-indexing.html#associatesite) and also see the discussion in the [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44497929/digital-assets-link-link-to-my-website). It stated that if your app is enrolled into Google Play Signing, APKs should be signed with upload key, while assetlink.json should have release key fingerprint.