# Android. Deep linking doesn't work with http/https scheme

Tags: android, deep-linking

I added a deep linking to my Android app this way:

```
<activity
        android:name=".views.DeepLinkingActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:scheme="https"
                android:host="example.com"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

When I click on `https://example.com` I get redirected to the web site.

When I change `android:scheme="https"` to `android:scheme="appscheme"` it works and it redirects me to my app.

How to force my app to be opened via `https` scheme?

UPDATE

I added a subdomain and it still doesn't work.

```
<activity
        android:name=".views.DeepLinkActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:scheme="https"
                android:host="www.example.ru"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: is your project package example.com? else replace it with your package name also try replacing host with this line  android:host="open" do these both and let me know

Comment: if I replace host with "open" how is it suppose to know from which site I want to be redirected?

Comment: it will redirect for all sites and links as soon as the schema matches

Comment: ok. my data look now this way - <data
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="open"/>
but no result. It redirects me to a web page

Comment: what your app package name?

Comment: It's com.company.apname

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156432/discussion-between-rainmaker-and-war-hero).

Comment: ok lets discuss it there

Comment: check this out https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking.html with path prefix you can use http/https schema

Comment: The same result. It works but not from browser. Did you have success with a http/https scheme?

Comment: Yes, see the second example in that link

Comment: I tried to put several data into intent-filter, but it still doesn't want to redirect me from https://example.com. Could you please update your answer with your solution?

Comment: Please replace the intent filter from the example and see if it works

Comment: <data android:scheme="https" android:host="example.ru" />
                <data android:scheme="app" android:host="open.my.app" /> - no result

Comment: Try this , you have missed out path prefix which is crucial in this example if we open wwww.example.com/gizmos it will ask and open the app <data android:scheme="http"
              android:host="www.example.com"
              android:pathPrefix="/gizmos" />

Comment: Works with https schema also, I tried and tested it myself

Comment: finally. it worked from the very beginning. The problem is - it doesn't work when I click on the link from my email. but if I click this link from (the button on a website) somewhere else - it works. Do you have an idea how to make it work from email letter?

Comment: Glad it worked, try Hyperlink with, link opening in New tab

Comment: I am facing the same issue when add url:scheme with my app name it opens the app but not with https. I have tried the answer given below but it couldn't work. can you please guid me about this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi please use the following data and try also refer this [doc](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking.html)

```
<intent-filter>
                <data
                    android:scheme="ou unique scheme(appname,package name)" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
```

OR

```
  <data
                android:scheme="you unique scheme(appname,package name)"
                android:host="www.example.ru"/>
```

Comment: How does it differ from the question and how does it solve the problem?

Comment: and why is it a selected answer?

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to [veritas1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46681238/2914140) I removed `android:autoVerify="true"` from https-scheme. I also changed the scheme from  `https` to `http`. (You can read about [autoVerify](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations)).

So, currently have two different schemes:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data
        android:host="your-site.com"
        android:pathPrefix="/"
        android:scheme="http"
        />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data
        android:host="your-site.com"
        android:pathPrefix="/"
        android:scheme="myapp"
        />
</intent-filter>
```

When clicking on a link myapp://your-site.com/... an application will be opened. When clicking on http://your-site.com/... Chrome browser will offer to open in the application or another browser, while other mobile browsers ignore this and try to open themselves.

UPDATE

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60342565/2914140 for App Linking.

Answer (score 1):

You refer to deep linking but `android:autoVerify="true"` is used for App linking, so the domain `example.com` (which you don't own?) is going to get checked for a digital asset links json file. See https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html

For your test to work I'd suggest removing `android:autoVerify="true"` and adding a subdomain to the host e.g. `android:host="www.example.com"`

Comment: I changed android:host="example.com" to android:host="www.example.com", deleted autoVerify, but no result, did i miss somth?

Comment: Now it says that connection is not secure. By the way I've added asset links file to the server according to your link but still no result

Comment: Any idea? Do you have at least one app which work with https?

Comment: Where does it say "connection is not secure"?, If it works correctly, you should be presented with the disambiguation dialog to select which app you would like to open the link, I have tested with and works fine.
You may have added the asset links file your app server, but it's `https://example.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json` that's going to be resolved as `example.com` is the domain your trying to verify.

Comment: I edited mt question like you said, look at it, but it doesn't work

Comment: Where has `android:host="www.example.ru"` come from? Just make sure the clickable link matches the host specified in the manifest.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156440/discussion-between-veritas1-and-rainmaker).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<activity
             android:name=".views.DeepLinkingActivity"
        android:exported="true">


           <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="open"
                    android:scheme="example" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="example.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="/"
                    android:scheme="http" />
            </intent-filter>
           <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="example.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="/"
                    android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: Define "example://" schema in your Branch.io application

Comment: But what if I have a https scheme?

Comment: yes we are defined both https and http also in intent-filter . It is working my side

Comment: And which Url should I click? example://example.com?

Comment: Create link on Branch.io dashboard

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156431/discussion-between-rainmaker-and-j-ramesh).

Comment: can you open your app with link which has https scheme? or it just works with an example scheme?

Answer (score 0):

Please check below it may be help

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-deep-linking/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0

Answer (score 0):

Just use **http**. Don't know when the implementation is changed.

But I just tested that using **http** will make both http and https work.

So change you intent filter by:

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">

<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

<data
    android:scheme="http"
    android:host="example.com"/>

</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

youe can also add to it

> sub.example.com

```
<intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="example.com" />
                <data android:scheme="app" android:host="com.example.example" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Comment: in my cas it was like this http://app.mydomain.com/idvalue so it worked with me

Comment: Thanks, I will try.

Comment: See the comment at the end of the [adding-filters](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking#adding-filters) section on duplicate data blocks.