# Android app link not working after the application is made live in play store

Tags: android, android-studio, android-app-links

I have implemented Android app links based on the below links.

https://developer.android.com/studio/write/app-link-indexing.html

https://developer.android.com/training/app-links

I have hosted `assetlinks` file into our domain https://ourdomain/.well-known/assetlinks.json
And also I have verified this using https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator
and from android studio's App Links Assitant also. and got verified status from both the ways.

Now when I generate a signed build and tested it via google drive links. Android app link works as expected(on click of the link the application gets open without opening disambiguation dialog for android version 6.0 and above).

After uploading the same version to the play store it's not working.

Below is the code used in the manifest file.

```
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:scheme="https"
                android:host="<ourdomain>" />
        </intent-filter>
```

EDIT: **Android app link did work as expected for one day after uploading it to the play store. and started opening disambiguation dialog again on the second day**. Any idea what could be the issue?

The same version from the play store gave me two different Statuses as **Ask** and **Always** on a different day.

[image]
[image]

> adb shell dumpsys package domain-preferred-apps

When I run the above command

Comment: what do you mean by it is not working ?

Comment: @waghydjemy Instead of opening the app directly on click of the link the disambiguation dialog pops up.

Comment: I am experiencing similar issues. Did you manage to fix this problem?

Answer (score 14):

I got into the same issue as it was working perfectly on the signed apk which was not uploaded to the playstore.

Later I found out that I need to add the SHA256 key from PlayConsole
By going to Application Dashboard in Play Console
then Release Management --> App Signing 
and there you will find SHA-256 certificate fingerprint
Use this SHA-256 in assetlinks.json at https://ourdomain/.well-known/assetlinks.json and then reinstall the app from playstore 
It started working fine for me

Comment: This solution worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instructions for the new Play Store:

Go to the Play Store, go to your **App's Dashboard**, go to **Setup/App Integrity** (on the left panel)

At the bottom of this page is your `Digital Asset Links JSON` which should be uploaded to https://ourdomain/.well-known/assetlinks.json