# Android applink disambiguation dialog when multiple domain declared

Tags: android, android-studio, manifest, deep-linking, android-app-links

Hi I'm trying to include the app-links as described here:
https://developer.android.com/training/app-links

Everything works fine with a single domain, but when I try to include multiple domains Android's system always shows the disambiguation dialog.

Is there any workaround to include multiple domains (not SUBdomains), in my manifest file avoiding to show disambiguation dialog?

Here my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleInstance" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
  <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
  </intent-filter>
  <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:host="exampl1.it" android:scheme="http" android:path="/applink"/>
  </intent-filter>
  <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:host="example1.it" android:scheme="https" android:path="/applink"/>
  </intent-filter>
  <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:host="p.example2.it" android:scheme="http"/>
  </intent-filter>
  <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:host="p.example2.it" android:scheme="https"/>
  </intent-filter>
  <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:host="example3.com" android:scheme="http" android:path="/path/to-deep"/>
  </intent-filter>
  <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:host="example3.com" android:scheme="https" android:path="/path/to-deep"/>
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/60342565/2914140. I divided all `<data>` tags into attributes:

```
<data android:scheme="https" />
<data android:host="example.com" />
```

Comment: hi there, I  tried your solution to divde all the <data> tags but still it does not work for me.

Comment: Do you mean that there will only be one intent filter with multiple data tags for each domains?

Comment: @BiswasKhayargoli, in other project we have `<intent-filter` with two `<data`. Each `<data` tag has two attributes: `android:host` and `android:scheme`. So, my solution won't work for all cases.