# Is there any way to force a link to open in Chrome from Facebook's in-app browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, inappbrowser

I've got a web app that requires the ability to print. Facebook's in-app implementation of Chrome doesn't allow printing. Currently, I'm giving the user instructions on how to open in chrome themselves in place of the print button I give normal users. But I'd prefer to just open Chrome for them when they get to that page, or at the very least provide a button/link that would open the page in Chrome instead of forcing them to find the settings button and figure out how to open Chrome themselves.

I've tried using the googlechrome://myurl.com approach, and Chrome opens, but the specified url doesn't load.

I've looked into [Google's Intent option](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents) but I wasn't able to figure out how to open Chrome with that method.

Is there a way to accomplish this in javascript? or by some url scheme in an href attribute?

So far, all the other answers I've found give explanations for how to do this from an Android App, but not from a website.

** Update: The googlechrome://myurl.com seems to work fine from iOS in the native facebook app. It does not appear to work correctly using the native facebook app in Android.

Comment: did you ever find a solution for Android?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

> googlechrome://navigate?url=example.com

for Android users.

Reference from https://stackoverflow.com/a/12013755/9514189

Comment: @Yash, I haven't been testing this lately, answer could be outdated.