# How to open external URL only in mobile's chrome browser from Ionic 4 app

Tags: cordova, google-chrome, ionic-framework, ionic4

From Ionic 4 mobile app, How can I open external URL only in chrome browser ? I have tried InAppBrowser with _system, but it is opening in default browser.

Can anyone please let me know that Is there any way using that I can open external URL only in chrome browser ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According [to this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12013755/156388), it seems that you can use the following to specifically target Google Chrome on Android:

```
"googlechrome://navigate?url=" + url
```

You could try plugging that into the url and see what happens?

On IOS you would need to find a different solution although all of the browsers are using the same rendering engine at their core so I don't know if you need it for that?