# Unable to open chrome browser using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, google-chrome, browser

I am trying to open a website in chrome from facebook's in app browser.

For that i am trying following code but it does not seem to open chrome.

```
window.location.href = 'googlechrome://navigate?url=example.com';
```

Meanwhile i can still open playstore market using

```
window.location.href = 'market://details?id=avscd';
```

Is there anything i am missing here or chrome changed way to open links?

Comment: Please check below link. it might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013416/is-there-any-way-in-android-to-force-open-a-link-to-open-in-chrome

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try doing it this way instead:

```
window.locaton  = "https://github.com/"
```

Thanks

Comment: please read the question, i am trying to open link in google chrome.