# Open intent in particular browser

Tags: android

In android when I am sending an intent with URL for example "google.com" the system will provide me the list of allowed browsers. How I can make it open that link in particular browser without choosing?

Comment: You need to create an explicit Intent, rather then implicit. I believe that this answer will be useful https://stackoverflow.com/a/27780129/10228281. Although the question is about Chrome, you can adapt it to the browser you want.

Comment: Keep in mind that in most cases, you shouldn't want to do this. It's a better experience for users if they can use their preferred browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open any url using specific browser by using its package but if browser not found in some device then have to handle exception.
Here,I am using chrome browser specifically to open this *https://www.google.com*

```
 Intent i=new Intent(ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.google.com"));
        i.setPackage("com.android.chrome");
        startActivity(i);
```

**Note -** I assume Chrome browser is available in device.

Answer (score -1):

You can use custom tab builder, something like this in your onClick function

```
val builder = CustomTabsIntent.Builder()
            builder.setToolbarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(),R.color.red))
            builder.setShowTitle(true)
            builder.build().launchUrl(requireContext(), Uri.parse(url))
          }
```