# Force in-app deeplink url to open in chrome instead of android app

Tags: kotlin, deep-linking

I have deeplinks in my Android app implemented like this:

```kotlin
<deepLink app:uri="acc-web.dotoo.app/en/dotoo/{dotoo_id}" />
```

Now I have some parts of our product on our web-app only, not yet on the android app. One of those functionalities is to buy tickets, for this the user has to go to the web-app that uses this url:

```kotlin
acc-web.dotoo.app/en/dotoo/{dotoo_id}?show-checkout-modal=true&email-address=${meInteractor.user?.email}
```

Which is matched to open the app.

When the user taps this link in the android app, it opens the android app again instead of the web-app and the user is in a loop. How can I fix this?

I open the browser like this from my app:

```kotlin
val browserIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(localePath))
startActivity(browserIntent)
```

Comment: You can find some solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013416/is-there-any-way-in-android-to-force-open-a-link-to-open-in-chrome