# Is there any way in Android to force open a link to an external browser?

Tags: java, android

My app consits of a web view and has the option to register as handler for links to https://example.com/news.

I have an 'Open in Browser' button that should open the current url in an external browser.

If my app is set as default handler for links to https://example.com/news, then the 'Open in Browser' button does not offer the option to open the url with a browser. Instead my app automaticalls opens the url.

I have seen that it's possible [force an app to open urls in chorme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013416/is-there-any-way-in-android-to-force-open-a-link-to-open-in-chrome), however I want a more general solution that works even if chorme is disabled/not installed. My question is then, how to open the url using **any** or the default browser?

The code for the 'Open in Browser' button:

```
if (url != null) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your implementation looks good to me and you can use it whether chrome is installed or not but you need to check if it is resolvable or not:

```
if (url != null) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    if (sendIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

If you want to show list of browsers to user to choose from you can use:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Choose Your Browser");
if (sendIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
     startActivity(chooser);
}
```

If your targetSdk is 30 or above take a look at this document too:
https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/use-cases