# open Chrome app on lollypop Android device with codenameone

Tags: android, codenameone

I have an old  Samsung Tablet E which I want to use with a Leaflet map.
The Android version is 5. The webpage is functioning on the tablet splendidly in the Google Chrome app, but doesn't show up in the webbrowsercomponent in my codenameone app which works with the system webview I use this oode too load the webpage. In Android 7 is my codenameapp also working splendidly.

```
private BrowserComponent bc;
private Form hi;  

    private void test2() {
   
            
            
     
    bc = new BrowserComponent();
       bc.setProperty("JavaScriptEnabled", true);
        bc.setProperty("AllowFileAccess", true);
        bc.setProperty("FileAccessFromFileURLs", true);
        
        
    bc.setURL("https://leafletjs.com/examples/accessibility/example.html") ; 
    hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, bc);
 
 
    hi.show();
    hi.revalidateWithAnimationSafety();
   
}
```

My questions

1. Is the code correct? Does it work with Android 5?
2. Or is there a work around to open webpage in Chrome app from a codename one app

Can somebody give me some code how I can open the Chrome app within codenameone and go to a specific external stored webpage?

Comment: I need more information. Does it work on other devices? In the simulator? What OS version is the device running? Can you try connecting the device with a cable and looking through logcat output? What code did you use to show that page? Typically it should just be the `BrowserComponent`.

Comment: With CodenameOne, in best case the package-name might vary, but one doesn't really need it (commenting instead of closing, because CodenameOne might behave differently). https://stackoverflow.com/a/27780129/549372

Comment: @MartinZeitler he's asking something different. If I understand correctly the `WebView` is working correctly in Android 7 but is failing to render correctly on Android 5.

Comment: Android 5.0 does have a Chrome based WebView but it's a separate element and not the same as the external browser so many behaviors might be different. Android 7.0 unified the code so the behavior should be similar. There might be a workaround for this particular case but I don't have an Android 5.x device. You would need to run on the device and see if something is printed to the console. If not this might get tricky to workaround.

Comment: oke how do i get the console visible in the codenameone app?

Comment: You need to connect using logcat to the device with a cable